# SFDX Script to copy all installed packages from one org to another one?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, jq

I have a specific error which depends on the packages installed in environment, to reproduce this error on the developer org, I need all the installed packages to install into development org.

Can I write a simple SFDX Script to copy all installed packages from one org to another one to automate this rather than having to install all of these manually?

Answer (score 3):

The following script can be used

```
for OUTPUT in $(sfdx force:package:installed:list -u $1 --json | jq '.result [] .SubscriberPackageVersionId'  -r)
do
    sfdx force:package:install -u $2 -w 500 -p  $OUTPUT -r 
done
```

Comment: Nice. See also [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/197699/2984) I wrote where you create a mdapi-style folder with a package.xml, and Salesforce can automatically install *all* the specified packages, with passwords, if necessary, in a single `force:mdapi:deploy` command.